# Javacript trying to access data from a nodelist?

Tags: javascript

We use a program for our business where you can text customers from a web based app. The app runs a program on the phone that handles all messages being received and being sent. The phone decided all of the sudden that it wanted to die. We still have the window open and we want to log the phone numbers. We found which class the phone numbers were stored under and we did a

```
const phoneNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.threadNameOrNumber');
```

we ran the variable and got a nodelist with 846 total pictured in image 2. We opened one of them up and in the nodelist breakdown
we noticed the phone number is listed in the innerHTML and innerText section as shown in image 3. We also noticed if you open "firstChild:" the phone number is again listed under data: and under textContent and wholeText

based off what i researched i need to loop through the nodelist to get just the phone numbers here was i tried so far

i tried first accessing one of the nodelist child to try and access the phone number so i did

```
let testNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.threadNameOrNumber')[110].innerText
```

when we ran `testNumber` we got the phone number back so i know i need to loop through it so i tried the following

```
for(let i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++){
  console.log(i);
}
```

i keep getting undefined for all the different loops i tried

[image: class name]

Image 2:

[image: image-2]

Image 3:

[image: image-3]

Comment: `console.log(phoneNumbers[i].innerText)` ?

Comment: it should be `document.querySelectorAll()` not `document.queryselectorall()`

Comment: @AnonymousCoder That must be a copying error, because the image shows the correct value in `phoneNumbers`.

Comment: @Barmar no friend, it's not the solution to the question. i am just pointing out so that he can be aware for that next time

Comment: Your second screenshot is cut off at the top. You must have typed something wrong in the `for` loop, because it should have logged the numbers from 0 to 845.

Comment: @AnonymousCoder yes that was typing error on my side